# Round-off error with SVG linear gradient in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, gradient, linear-gradients, rounding-error

I'm seeing some issues recently with Chrome to render SVG linear gradient. Have a look at this SVG below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<svg>
  <g>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="79px" x2="706px" y1="0" y2="0">
      <stop class="" offset="54.54545454545455%" style="stop-color: red;"></stop>
      <stop class="" offset="63.63636363636364%" style="stop-color: red;"></stop>
      <stop class="" offset="63.63636363636364%" style="stop-color: green;"></stop>
      <stop class="" offset="72.72727272727273%" style="stop-color: green;"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path d="M79,241L136,196L193,194L250,212L307,159L364,152L421,339L478,46L535,205L592,134L649,215L706,74"
    style="opacity: 1; fill: none; stroke: url(#linearGradient); stroke-width: 2px;">
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

After loading this html in Chrome(my version is 23.0.1271.64), it is very easy to see a clear 2px error of the linear gradient in the peek, which shows some green color in the left side line segment. In both IE 9 and latest Firefox, the svg is rendered correctly. I think it maybe a bug of Chrome or WebKit. Does anyone know how to workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Google confirmed this bug:[http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161919](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161919). Any idea about the workaround?

Comment: Were you ever able to get any further information about working around this problem?

Comment: Sorry, at this moment no.